# How to make Trigger Action by Reaction Posted on MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, bots, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am making bot works for Microsoft Teams.

> Goal: To make bot to detect reaction posted for any messages in the user's MS teams channel.

**Problems:
Using `onReactionsAdded` in activityhandler(MS BotFramework) , my bot detects the reaction posted only for the bot messages**

Is there any possible way to make trigger action by posting reaction for users' posts in MS Teams?

Answer (score 0):

@Cambria a Bot receive's the reactionAdded event only when there is a reaction on a message the Bot itself posted. Reacting on a user's post does not trigger an event with the Bot.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the fact that you Bot won't receive every single message posted in the channel / group chat - only those that "@mention" your bot. It's different in a 1-1 chat with the bot though - there it will receive everything. If you want to make sure you get every single reaction, you'd need to call the Graph for that. See [Get a reply to a channel message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-messagereply?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) as an example - right near the bottom of the page it shows "reactions" (it's empty in that example).